# "curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | sudo apt-key add -" are we supposed to add some key here?

Tags: ubuntu, docker

I am trying to install docker on ubuntu and following installation guide I came across this command.

```
"curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | sudo apt-key add -"
```

And in its responce I get OK and nothing really downloads. Am I suppose to provide a key or what is the purpose of this curl command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `apt-key add` adds a trusted key to for the docker repository. The curl command is downloading this key and piping it to the `apt-key add` command which adds it as a trusted key.

```
>man apt-key

COMMANDS
Add filename
Add a new key to the list of trusted keys. The key is read from the filename 
given with the parameter filename or if the filename is - from standard 
input.

It is critical that keys added manually via apt-key are verified to belong 
to the owner of the repositories they claim to be for otherwise the apt-
secure(8) infrastructure is completely undermined.
```

In short, This command downloads the key as adds it as a trusted key.

Comment: where the key is stored? Is it in some file format?

Comment: @AnamNizami You can download the key by going to the curl url https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg. Its text format, you can open with any text editor.

Comment: Or just remove the pipe to `apt-key` and see what `curl` prints.  You can save to a file with `curl -o`.

Answer (score 1):

I done this in a alternative way to make to understand !

**1. stored key to a file**

```
#curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/debian/gpg > key_stored2file
```

**2. Add a new key to the list of trusted keys.**

```
#apt-key add key_stored2file
OK
```

**If `-` given instead of filename( in above example `key_stored2file`) then it will take from standard input so it can be run as a single command as follows**

```
#curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/debian/gpg | sudo apt-key add -
```